# Deleting iPhone pics using my Mac?

Tags: iphone

How do I delete iPhone photographs using my Mac? I have tried using Image Capture and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to the problem in your question is the following.

After the import procedure in the application Photos you can select the option of delete photo from the device (iPhone in your case) immediately after the importing procedure.